# How to show ThreadName in grafana?

Tags: jmeter, grafana, influxdb

I have a script with six ThreadGropus. I sent data to influx and prestens them in grafana (Backendlistener).
My problem - I want to present (like a variable) a name of ThreadGroup on top bar and when I choose o Group, charts should be refresh and show only for chosen ThreadGroup.
Is thas possible ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhStA.png)

Answer (score 1):

It is not very possible to provide the answer without knowing what is your [Backend Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Backend_Listener) configuration and what [JMeter Dashboard](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards?search=jmeter) you're using.

- One of the options is to add [__threadGroupName() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadGroupName) as the prefix for all Samplers, this way you will be able to distinguish the Samplers coming from different Thread Groups and filter by their name
- Another option is using top-level [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller/) and move your Samplers to be its children

Example test plan:

[image]

Example dashboard:

[image]