# How to choose between JMeter ThreadGroups in grafana?

Tags: jmeter, grafana, influxdb

i have a script with a few thread groups and i would like to select which one metrics to see. Im using InfluxDB, Grafana and JMeter. In grafana im using [this](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/5496) dashboard and i've followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62816104/how-to-show-threadname-in-grafana) instructions but when i try to select a transaction in Grafana it says none.[This is my backend listener configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peJG6.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had **really** "followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62816104/how-to-show-threadname-in-grafana)" you would see that the guy there sets `summaryOnly` setting to `false`

I do believe if you "follow" that step as well you will be able to "choose" the transaction names from the dropdown (given they're present in InfluxDB)

More information: [How to Use Grafana to Monitor JMeter Non-GUI Results - Part 2](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-grafana-to-monitor-jmeter-non-gui-results-part-2)

Comment: Thaank you sir! Didnt realise about that, im sorry! Now its working perfectly :)